# Matching based on column vector

Tags: r, matrix, pattern-matching, match

I need to create a  matrix based on matching the names of a column vector between two others. The first column of the new matrix must be stored as a character. All other elements must be numeric.

Setup:

```
Mat1 <- matrix(nrow=9, ncol =1, data = c(as.character(letters[1:6]), as.character(letters[4:6])))

> Mat1
      [,1]
 [1,] "a" 
 [2,] "b" 
 [3,] "c" 
 [4,] "d" 
 [5,] "e" 
 [6,] "f" 
 [7,] "d" 
 [8,] "e" 
 [9,] "f"

Mat2 <- matrix(nrow =6, ncol =7)
Mat2[,1] <- c(as.character(letters[1:6]))
Mat2[,2:7] <- rnorm(36,0,1)

> Mat2
     [,1] [,2]                  [,3]                 [,4]                 [,5]                  [,6]                 [,7]                
[1,] "a"  "1.32211169385647"    "-0.794434986759682" "0.203970950970836"  "-0.441620688859017"  "-1.03106550665928"  "-2.36371498932037" 
[2,] "b"  "-1.20504499406439"   "0.661565696639345"  "-0.130674576341411" "-1.72029664687886"   "-0.124936351917991" "1.94820336129856"  
[3,] "c"  "-0.0810637820636855" "0.331843774960614"  "1.57618066036272"   "0.347192690698403"   "0.461148562862295"  "-0.621437469825553"
[4,] "d"  "-1.00423289944797"   "-1.18209253532912"  "-0.902634429227515" "-0.0501872874215649" "0.777730959043326"  "1.27934713546954"  
[5,] "e"  "0.187406680866054"   "0.85035679353673"   "1.5813056522447"    "-0.902115545267143"  "-0.367493958847359" "1.78954559062418"  
[6,] "f"  "0.698909561506112"   "-0.580247182127906" "1.90094682857056"   "1.4732475343253"     "-0.509183264239919" "0.108843900636093"
```

```
output <- matrix(nrow=nrow(Mat1), ncol = ncol(Mat2))
output[,1] <- Mat1[,1]
output[1:6,2:7] <- Mat2[1:6,2:7]
output[7:9, 2:7] <- mat2[4:6, 2:7]

  output
      [,1] [,2]                  [,3]                 [,4]                 [,5]                  [,6]                 [,7]                
 [1,] "a"  "1.32211169385647"    "-0.794434986759682" "0.203970950970836"  "-0.441620688859017"  "-1.03106550665928"  "-2.36371498932037" 
 [2,] "b"  "-1.20504499406439"   "0.661565696639345"  "-0.130674576341411" "-1.72029664687886"   "-0.124936351917991" "1.94820336129856"  
 [3,] "c"  "-0.0810637820636855" "0.331843774960614"  "1.57618066036272"   "0.347192690698403"   "0.461148562862295"  "-0.621437469825553"
 [4,] "d"  "-1.00423289944797"   "-1.18209253532912"  "-0.902634429227515" "-0.0501872874215649" "0.777730959043326"  "1.27934713546954"  
 [5,] "e"  "0.187406680866054"   "0.85035679353673"   "1.5813056522447"    "-0.902115545267143"  "-0.367493958847359" "1.78954559062418"  
 [6,] "f"  "0.698909561506112"   "-0.580247182127906" "1.90094682857056"   "1.4732475343253"     "-0.509183264239919" "0.108843900636093" 
 [7,] "d"  "-1.00423289944797"   "-1.18209253532912"  "-0.902634429227515" "-0.0501872874215649" "0.777730959043326"  "1.27934713546954"  
 [8,] "e"  "0.187406680866054"   "0.85035679353673"   "1.5813056522447"    "-0.902115545267143"  "-0.367493958847359" "1.78954559062418"  
 [9,] "f"  "0.698909561506112"   "-0.580247182127906" "1.90094682857056"   "1.4732475343253"     "-0.509183264239919" "0.108843900636093
```

Comment: `merge(Mat1, Mat2)`

Comment: Mat2[match(Mat1, unique(Mat1)),] will work. But it doesn't work when i move to my actual sample

Comment: Start by simplifying `as.character(letters[1:6])` is exactly the same as `letters[1:6]`.

Comment: merge(Mat1, Mat2) doesn't preserve ordering

Comment: `Mat2[match(Mat1[, 1], Mat2[, 1]), ]` this seems to work on your sample data.